# Vuex - mapGetters et al but mapping by parameter

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to create a general filter component which get's it's data from the store

Right now, I'm using `mapGetters` like so

```
...mapGetters({
  items: 'filters'
}),
```

But I would like to be able to generalize this to which getter I'm mapping

```
props: {
  filterType: String
},

computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
    items: this.filterType
  }),
}
```

This gives me the following error

```
Cannot read property 'nombre' of undefined
```

I know that I can do:

```
computed: {
  items: function () {
      return this.$store.getters[this.filterType]
  }
}
```

but I just wanted to check if there is a way to use the properties of the vue instance with the mapGetters, or if you need to strictly hardcode the getters names inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe that's what you are looking for (or at least closest to the use of `mapGetters`):

```
props: {
   filterType: String
},

computed: {
  ...mapState({
    items(state, getters) {
      return getters[this.filterType];
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Any idea how you would do this with an array of getters in Vuex 4? filterType: ['getter1', 'getter2']

Comment: I'm sorry @WillyBurb but I stopped working with Vue about a year and a half ago. I'm not up to date with newer versions of Vue or Vuex...